# How to pass values from p:selectOneMenu to managed bean and get it back into view using p:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

xhtml code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="destinationCountryId" style="width:150px" value="#{trafficMBean.traffic.destinationCountryId}" required="true" requiredMessage="Destination Country is required" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{trafficMBean.countries}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.countryname}" itemValue="#{country.id}" />
            <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{trafficMBean.getCountrySpecificBranchList}" immediate="true"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

<p:outputLabel for="destinationBranchId" value="Destination Branch: "/>
<p:selectOneMenu id="destinationBranchId" style="width:150px" value="#{trafficMBean.traffic.destinationDsvBranchId}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{trafficMBean.branches}" var="branch" itemLabel="#{branch.branchname}" itemValue="#{branch.id}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Managed Bean method:

```
public void getCountrySpecificBranchList(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){
        logger.debug("AJAX called Inside TrafficMBean getCountrySpecificBranchList method component is "+e.getComponent()); 
        int i = (Integer)((UIOutput)e.getSource()).getValue();
        logger.debug("AJAX called Inside TrafficMBean getCountrySpecificBranchList method source is "+i);
        logger.debug("AJAX called Inside TrafficMBean getCountrySpecificBranchList method string is "+e.toString());
        //Need to process my country ID and get only those branches which are there for this country.
```

//And send this updated branches list to JSF page
            //int cid = traffic.getDestinationCountryId();
            //logger.debug("AJAX called leaving TrafficMBean getCountrySpecificBranchList method:: coountry Id selected is ::>"+cid);
        }

How should i get the selected value of country dropdown from JSF and passit to managed bean. After fetching and processing in managed bean, how should I get the updated values back in JSF and into my branches select tag.

Comment: That's what the `value` attribute of `p:selectOneMenu` is supposed to be for...

Comment: In your country dropown, in your p:ajax add update="destinationBranchId". In the method `getCountrySpecificBranchList` you need to fill the branches dropdown, and store those values in the `branches` variable...